# Отключить autofocus для input в fancybox

Tags: html5, fancybox

Здравствуйте коллеги, возник вопрос, в сплывающем модальном окне fancybox есть поле для ввода телефона, при открытии autofocus сразу открывает клавиатуру для ввода, очень неприятно выходит. Так как убрать autofocus у этого input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как вариант, раз уже есть jQuery.

```
$('(input selector)').removeAttr('autofocus');
```

можно и в самой библиотеке поискать, где автофокус присваивается и удалить там.

Comment: Спасибо!!! Первый вариант не подошёл, второй более действенный оказался

Answer (score 1):

какой fancybox? 
Если 3 то в [опциях](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#options) открытия окна задать параметр `autoFocus:false`.

Если 2 то как предложили в ответе.

Comment: Я так  и сделал!

Answer (score 0):

Если fancybox 3, то используем пример из официальной документации:

```
$('[data-fancybox=""]').fancybox({
    autoFocus: false
});
```